# Identifying this small tree-shaped succulent

Tags: identification, succulents

I bought this at a succulent store earlier this year, but it wasn't labelled. Could anyone tell me what sort of plant it is?

It has 7-pointed flowers and marks on the "trunk" where old leaves have fallen off.

[image: succulent image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Dorstenia Foetida bonsai plant and it's cute...

Comment: Thanks! It is cute...